# consume json webservice from IOS with null

Tags: ios, json, web-services

I use code like the following

```
  NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"urladdress", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, PAGE_COUNT, API_KEY];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlAsString];
    NSLog(@"%@", urlAsString);
```

but I have web service method that take string as parameter (may be null or empty) how to create the url of this method

I tried  `http://EgySchools.com/datawebservices/getcategories`

how to continue to add the parameters

Comment: The pattern of characters after the site URL is matched to "routes" defined within the server.  "abc.com/x/y" is different from "abc.com/x/y/z".  The values may or may not be considered variables -- eg, "abc.com/x/y/z" and "abc.com/x/q/z" might be handled by the same server method, with the "y" or "q" being a parameter to the method, or they might be routed to entirely different methods.

Comment: (But your first line above is nonsense, of course, since it will only produce the URL "urladdress" as there are no `%` substitution points in the string.)